# Sql query to get sum of Amounts based on the TaxType Code

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have my table datas as follows

```
EmpID    FedTaxID    TaxTypeCode   Amount
1059    888888888   TX02        2000
1059    888888888   TX02        3000
1059    888888888   TX03        5010
```

I am using `self join` to get the total amount based on `FedTaxID and TaxTypeCode`. I write as follows

`SELECT     SUM(t1.Amount) AS Expr1, SUM(t2.Amount) AS Expr2
FROM         tblTest AS t1 CROSS JOIN
                      tblTest AS t2
WHERE     (t1.FedTaxID = '888888888') AND (t2.FedTaxID = '888888888') AND (t1.TaxTypeCode = 'tx02') AND (t2.TaxTypeCode = 'tx03')`

But it is returning the amount as follows

```
 Expr1      Expr2 
 5000   10020
```

My expected output is

```
 Expr1      Expr2 
  5000     5010
```

So can any one tell where i went wrong please. Also i need the total sum of those 2 so can any one help me on that too

Comment: Do you really need the output in columns?  You can't just do `select TaxTypeCode, sum(amount) from tblTest where FedTaxID='88888888' and TaxTypeCode in('TX02','TX03') group by TaxTypeCode` and interpret it at the client?

Comment: `@forsvair` this works great i need the total sum of those how can i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much better to use a "CASE" statement for this sort of thing:

```
SELECT FedTaxId, SUM(tx02t) as tx02_tot , SUM(tx03t) as tx03tot , SUM(Txallt) as txnntot
  FROM (SELECT CASE WHEN  TaxTypeCode = 'tx02' THEN Amount else 0 END as tx02t,
               CASE WHEN  TaxTypeCode = 'tx03' THEN Amount else 0 END as tx03t,
               Amount as txallt
        FROM tbltest
        WHERE FedTaxID = '888888888'
       ) 
GROUP BY FedTaxId
```

Comment: I don't get why you're doing a group by FedTaxId at the end of that... It seems a bit redundant.

Comment: Hi `James` i need the total sum too means `5000+5010=10010`

Comment: Dorababu -- see edit. @forsvarir correct -- but I am assuming his real life problem involves some sort of grouping by tax code or employee.

Comment: Hi `James` while writing this in stored procedure i am getting an error as `Incorrect sentence near the Keyword GROUP`

Comment: @Dorababu, see EDIT. -- or hust skip the group by as it is redundant is this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a handy SQL instance to check my syntax, but you might be able to do this using PIVOT:

```
Select ['TX02'], ['TX03']
FROM
(
    Select TaxTypeCode, Sum(Amount) as Total
    From tblTest
    Group By TaxTypeCode
) as SourceTable
PIVOT
(
Sum(Total)
FOR TaxTypeCode IN (['TX02'], ['TX03'])
) AS PivotTable
```

UPDATE:
With FedTaxID (again, with a grain of salt, I don't have a way to check this right now):

```
Select ['TX02'], ['TX03']
FROM
(
    Select FedTaxID, TaxTypeCode, Sum(Amount) as Total
    From tblTest
    Group By FedTaxID, TaxTypeCode
) as SourceTable
PIVOT
(
Sum(Total)
FOR TaxTypeCode IN (['TX02'], ['TX03'])
) AS PivotTable
```

Comment: How about my condition then i also used `FedTaxID`

Answer (score 1):

Just do a simple `GROUP BY` and use `WITH ROLLUP` for the totals:

```
SELECT 
    TaxTypeCode, SUM(Amount) 
FROM 
    tblTest 
WHERE
    FedTaxID = '888888888'
    AND TaxTypeCode IN ('TX02', 'TX03')
GROUP BY
    TaxTypeCode WITH ROLLUP
```

Should give you an output something like this:

```
 TaxTypeCode    (No column name)
    TX02           5000
    TX03           5010
    NULL          10010              -- this is the line with the totals
```

Comment: Hi this give the desired result but what about my condition `FedTaxID`

Comment: Ok but will this search as per the i needed because i should add amounts when `TaxTypeCode=tx02` and `TaxTypeCode=tx03` but as per your statement this will add irrespective of `TaxTypeCode`if i am not wrong

Comment: Hi `Marc_s` if i write this in store procedure this is stating an error as `Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.` can you tell why

Comment: @Dorababu: create a new question and post the stored procedure code .... just from this I cannot possibly know what's wrong....

Comment: `Marc-s` how can i use you query so  that it should display only total sum

Comment: @Dorababu: `SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM  tblTest WHERE FedTaxID = '888888888' AND TaxTypeCode IN ('TX02', 'TX03')`

Answer (score 0):

You're adding up the value twice, So `expr1 = 2000 + 3000 = 5000`

But expr you're adding also twice, so `5010 + 5010 = 10020`.

Tjeu

Comment: What should i do to get my desired output

Comment: I'm not sure why it's doing this though.

What's the result if you try

    SELECT SUM(t1.Amount) AS Expr1, SUM(t2.Amount) AS Expr2 
    FROM tblTest AS t1 CROSS JOIN tblTest AS t2 
    WHERE ((t1.FedTaxID = '888888888') AND (t1.TaxTypeCode = 'tx02'))
    AND ((t2.FedTaxID = '888888888') AND (t2.TaxTypeCode = 'tx03'))

Comment: I post the result for that query `Expr1      Expr2 
 5000   10020`

Comment: Don't put large text blocks into comments - there is no way to format those! Please update your response by editing it and provide additional information....

Answer (score 0):

Your cross join leads to two rows of data being returned, looking something like the following

```
2000 5010
3000 5010
```

So, if you sum those up you get the result you're seeing.

I'm sure it isn't the best way but subqueries would work.